# Why is std::FILE in capital letters?

Tags: c++, c, naming

I was wondering why C's and C++'s FILE type is spelled with capital letters. Other types are spelled with lower case letters.

**Edit** see § 27.9.2 of C++11, table 134

Comment: Because it evolved from plain C `FILE`?

Comment: [Tradition!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRdfX7ut8gw) - a.k.a. backwards compatibility

Comment: I've seen that question before on SO several weeks ago, but it's not turning up in search...

Comment: One of many unfortunate inconsistencies that were kept for backwards compatibility.  Just like `creat()` function and others alike.

Comment: @AndréCaron Not to mention, `FOPEN_MAX`, `_IONBF` and even `stderr`,`stdin` _macros_ (sic)

Comment: its there for backwards compatibility but ok to use as it is part of the C standard.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: That seems to be begging the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In *very old* dialects of C, before there was any of standardization, when the FILE type was invented, and before typedef existed, that name was a macro:

```
#define FILE struct _iobuf
```

The convention was to have macros named in all uppercase.

http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/include/stdio.h

(the macros that were in lowercase were simply optimized versions of functions - many of them also existed as proper functions)

Comment: I can understand use of macros as inline functions, but wouldn't type aliases use `typedef`?  Was this *before* the advent of `typedef`?

Comment: @AndréCaron The V7 /usr/include directory only contains "typedef" once - defining `jmp_buf` to `int[3]`. It's possible that setjmp/longjmp was written later than stdio or that an earlier version of setjmp/longjmp existed that did not use a typedef jmp_buf. Or it's possible that at some point typedefs didn't work with structs.